# Clean up event log by script

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

Any way to remove all entries from the Windows event logs (Application, System & Software) apart from the last 24 hours?

Via command line such as batch file.

On Windows 2008 R2 Server & Windows 7

Comment: Which version of Window are you using? If >= Vista/2008 you can use wevtutil for accomplish the task http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you want to do this? You can just set the logs to overwrite themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are trying to do. You can either save or clear an event log. When you clear, you can optionally save the events before clearing.

**EDIT**

Looking again, that wasn't very helpful. You can't remove some events from an event log without removing them all. You can, however, export some events based on a filter. For example, the following command will export all events logged to the System event log in the last 24 hours:

`wevtutil epl system c:\system.evtx /q:"*[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]]]"`

Does this get closer to what you want? If not, can you clarify if there is something more we can help with?

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 1 Then
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript ""Clear Event Logs.vbs"" [computer name]"
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Quit
End If

Dim strComputer ' As String

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    strComputer= WScript.Arguments(0)
Else
    strComputer= "localhost"
End If

ClearEventLogs strComputer

WScript.Echo "Done"

Private Sub ClearEventLogs( _
    strComputer)

    WScript.Echo "Clearing event logs on " & strComputer & "..."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
        "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Backup)}!\\" _
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
        "Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile")

    For Each objLogfile in colLogFiles
        ClearEventLog strComputer, objLogfile.LogfileName
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ClearEventLog( _
    strComputer, _
    strEventLogName)

    WScript.Echo "Clearing '" & strEventLogName & "' event log on " _
        & strComputer & "..."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject( _
        "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Backup)}!\\" _
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
        "Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile where LogFileName='" _
            & strEventLogName & "'")

    For Each objLogfile in colLogFiles
    Dim backupFilename
    backupFilename= "C:\" & strEventLogName & "_" & GetFormattedTimestamp() _
        & ".evt"

        errBackupLog = objLogFile.BackupEventLog(backupFilename)
        If errBackupLog <> 0 Then        
            WScript.Echo "The " & strEventLogName & " event log on " _
                & strComputer & " could not be backed up."
        Else
            objLogFile.ClearEventLog()
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetFormattedTimestamp()
    Dim timestamp
    timestamp = Now

    GetFormattedTimestamp = Year(timestamp) _
        & LPad(Month(timestamp), 2, "0") _
        & LPad(Day(timestamp), 2, "0") _
        & "_" & Replace(FormatDateTime(timestamp, 4), ":", "")

End Function

Private Function LPad( _
    strValue, _
    nLength, _
    strPadCharacter)

    Dim strPaddedValue

    strPaddedValue = strValue

    While (Len(strPaddedValue) < nLength)
        strPaddedValue = strPadCharacter & strPaddedValue
    WEnd

    LPad = strPaddedValue
End Function
```

here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2011/03/01/script-to-clear-and-save-event-logs.aspx

Another note from the blog: run it using cscript, not wscript.

Comment: How is this excluding the last 24 hours?

Comment: it's not, but it doesn't delete the last 24 either...this is pretty much the simplest way to archive the logs.  There are other scripts out there that will do something similar that work by parsing through the log event by event.  I could pull one of those out for you...maybe you could do the backup and rather than clearing the whole thing, just delete individual entries.  Depending on how secure your environment is I don't think the security log will like being tampered with in this way, however.